# Minus infinity in Python as a result of for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, infinity

I am trying to calculate valocity in Python with for loop. But when I run my code, I get "-inf" as a result for every row.

This is my code:

```
Vx = 0
for i in range(1, len(x_axis.timestamp)):
    Vx += Vx + (x_axis.diff_ts[i]) * float(x_axis.value_x[i-1])
    x_axis['Vx'] = Vx
print(x_axis)
```

Vx is my new column. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

When I check dtypes, I get this:

```
timestamp           float64
value_x              object
y_axis              float64
z_axis              float64
diff_ts             float64
```

My data looks like:

```
        timestamp          value_x  ...  lag(timestamp,1)  diff_ts
0     1.661847e+09     -8.579621315  ...      0.000000e+00    0.000
1     1.661847e+09  -8.586804389953  ...      1.661847e+09    0.020
2     1.661847e+09   -8.56884765625  ...      1.661847e+09    0.020
3     1.661847e+09     -8.579621315  ...      1.661847e+09    0.020
4     1.661847e+09   -8.58800125122  ...      1.661847e+09    0.021
```

Reproducible example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'timestamp': [1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09],
        'value_x': [-8.56884765625, -8.573636055, -8.58201599121, -8.565256118774, -8.58201599121],
        'diff_ts': [0.000, 0.020, 0.021, 0.020, 0.020]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['value_x'] = df['value_x'].astype(object, errors='raise')
print(df.info())
print(df)

Vx = 0
for i in range(1, len(df.timestamp)):
    Vx = Vx + (df.diff_ts[i]) * float(df.value_x[i-1])
    df['Vx'] = Vx
print(df)
```

Comment: Did you mean `Vx += Vx + ...`? I suspect you meant `Vx = Vx + ...`. As you've written it, it causes `Vx` to approximately double each time, which may cause -inf if the number of steps in the for loop is large enough.

Comment: Hi @PaulHankin, when I do that, I get the same value for every row...

Comment: Sorry then, it's impossible to debug given only the code you've posted in the question. Can you provide initial values for the variables, ie a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: Hi @PaulHankin, I edited the question with data..

Comment: Can you make a minimal reproducible example -- that is, a small piece of code that other people can run that reproduces the problem?

Comment: @PaulHankin
` import pandas as pd

data = {'timestamp':[1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09, 1.661848e+09],
        'value_x': [-8.56884765625, -8.573636055, -8.58201599121, -8.565256118774, -8.58201599121],
        'diff_ts': [0.000, 0.020, 0.021, 0.020, 0.020]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['value_x'] = df['value_x'].astype(object, errors='raise')
print(df.info())
print(df)

Vx = 0
for i in range(1, len(df.timestamp)):
    Vx = Vx + (df.diff_ts[i]) * float(df.value_x[i-1])
    df['Vx'] = Vx
print(df) `

Comment: Can you put it in your question please, with correct formatting?

Comment: Yes, I just did it.

Comment: This doesn't give any -inf does it?

Comment: It doesn´t, but when I run it on my data with 11012 rows, it does.

Comment: Perhaps you meant: `df['Vx'][i] = Vx`? And then you need to look for the row where the -inf first appears because I guess there's some bad data in there

Comment: It's suspicious that you have `df['value_x'] = df['value_x'].astype(object, errors='raise')`... why are you converting a column of float values to object, and then back to float when you use it in your calculation?

Comment: I just sent my data to csv, and there is no inf or bad data in there, everything is in order.

@PaulHankin I did that, because when I get my data from DB, value_x is an object, and I wanted to cretae the same thing...

Comment: In the loop, add the lines `print(Vx, df.diff_ts[i], df.value_x[i-1])` and `assert abs(Vx) < 1e9`. Assuming the assertion fails on your full data set, include the last 3 or 4 lines of the output in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`df['Vx'] = Vx` will set `Vx` as value for the whole column.
So if at the last iteration `Vx = -inf`, the column will have `-inf` at every row.

You can use `df.at[<row>, <col>] = <val>` to set a single value at (`<row>`, `<col>`) position.

As @Paul Hankin mentioned in the comments, the `+=` in `Vx += Vx + (x_axis.diff_ts[i]) * float(x_axis.value_x[i-1])` might result in `-inf` at some point if the number of iteration is high enough.

By the way, there is a mismatch between the first code snippet and the reproducible example, since in the latter you don't use the `+=`.

Try using `at` as mentioned above and `Vx = Vx + ...` instead of `Vx += Vx ...` and see if you still encounter the same issue.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with the example, and it really works, then I do it with my data, and it gives me what I need, but somewhere it starts again with -inf, and it is right after when I have calculated value of Vx -1.2490515370225215e+308, I assume that is the problem....